# Что может делать оживление, кроме как царить?

Tags: выбор-слов, синонимы

Из рабочего момента:

> Возле крутой лестницы на второй этаж (СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОЕ ДАЙ! ОБИТЕЛИ?
>   ЦАРСТВА?) отшельниц царило небывалое оживление.

"Обитель" слева-справа-вверху-внизу: остановилась на царстве. Но дальше-то царит оживлянс! И как же ж жить?

> «Глаза всё более разгорались оживлением». Максим Горький.

Да не хочу я списывать у пролетарского писателя, да и не нравится...

Мне - ПОЖАЛУЙСТА! - глагол к оживлению.

[Синонимы к оживлению:](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/102566/%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

> активность, рост; воскрешение, веселость, восстановление, воскресение,
>   веселье, оживленность, возрождение, бум, встряхивание, активизация,
>   растормаживание, возобновление, жизнь, оживание, реанимация, движение,
>   авиваж, оживляж, обновление, очеловечение, приподнятое настроение,
>   веселое настроение, возвращение к жизни, биение жизни, воскрешение из
>   мертвых, освежение, взбадривание, стаффаж, реанимирование, жизнь бьет
>   ключом.

С синонимами к "царить" совсем кранты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, мне кажется, оставить вообще без глагола:
**Возле крутой лестницы на второй этаж царства отшельниц — небывалое оживление.**

Или использовать такие (может, для оживления в царстве и подойдут?):
наблюдалось, ощущалось, сквозило, чувствовалось, вспыхнуло, возникло, господствовало, пра́вило, вита́ло.

Comment: А зачем над *правило* ударение? По-другому его и не поставишь ни в каком смысле.

Comment: Поставишь. Теоретически: слово "пра́ви́ло". https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило

Comment: Ха, спасибо, Римма, любопытно!

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о конкретном моменте времени, я бы поставил просто "было". Если о постоянстве и надо выразить, что там всегда оживление, то "господствовало", хотя "царило" мне больше нравится.

Ну а "разгоралось" - это о моменте его зарождения: только что всё было тихо и вот прямо сейчас всё начало оживляться и действовать, и становится всё активнее и активнее. Оно никак не является взаимозаменяемым с "царило".